# How is heat generated to start combustion in an incinerator?

Tags: power-electronics, heat, energy

I see many diagrams on the internet that show a layout diagram of an incinerator that has a combustion chamber connected to a boiler or gas turbine to capture the energy mechanically or generate electricity and a gas scrubber to filter the exhaust from different types of particles before discharging to the atmosphere.

For example:

[image]

What's missing is the apparatus to start the combustion. Typically, it could be natural gas or fossil fuels in the same way a campfire or barbecue pit.

Is it possible that electricity alone can be used to generate heat that would cause the incinerated materials to start combustion and provide the fuel for more incoming materials?

For example, if I had a three-phase existing oven, could the heating element be used as part of the incinerator component?

If electricity is solely used as the fuel source without a combination of other fuels to start the first combustion, how effective would it be to generate back the electricity/heat energy from subsequent combustion?

Comment: Since this integrates multiple engineering disciplines aside from just electronics design, you might be able to get answers that involve a wider understanding of those disciplines on  [engineering.se].

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But one thing to consider is whether the maximum combustion temperature is too high for your heating element. Another thing to consider is whether the chemical environment and oxidation/reduction environment is compatible with your heating element. Certainly electrically powered furnaces exist. But for very high temperatures, it can be challenging for the heating element to survive.

Comment: A coal plant I have worked on, had 4 oil burners to start combustion, I guess there are plenty of other possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Biomass burners use ceramic heating elements to heat the airstream to over 1000°C to ignite the fuel. Image source: [Ecofit Technology](http://ecofittechnology.ie/fkk-wood-pellet-igniters/).*

It's only necessary to get the fire going in a small spot and then crank up the air supply.

| Question | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| What's missing is the apparatus to start the combustion. Typically, it could be natural gas or fossil fuels in the same way a campfire or barbecue pit. | Or a hot air supply. |
| Is it possible that electricity alone can be used to generate heat that would cause the incinerated materials to start combustion and provide the fuel for more incoming materials? | Certainly. My wood pellet boiler works in that manner. |
| For example, if I had a three-phase existing oven, could the heating element be used as part of the incinerator component? | Unlikely. You need the air stream. Once fire has started you switch off the element and keeping it out of the fire will prolong its life. |
| If electricity is solely used as the fuel source without a combination of other fuels to start the first combustion, how effective would it be to generate back the electricity / heat energy from subsequent combustion? | It will be a tiny loss in the overall system. My boiler's starter will draw maybe 0.5 kW for, say, five minutes (= 0.5 × 5 / 60 = 0.04 kWh) and outputs 20 kW so the starter uses 0.2% of the energy the boiler gives out in the first hour. |